# Where to run income poll

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, polling

I would like to run a poll on the income of people. What is the best StackExchange platform to run this on?

Comment: Certainly that would be closed as "not constructive" on *any* site?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm sorry, but we don't allow that kind of solicitation on our sites.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. I was also very unsure about where to ask for this. Too sad since I guess there is a big demand for such solicitations.

Comment: @JJD No worries. Thanks for checking first. :)

Comment: I should imagine that you could advertise a poll of this kind on one carefully selected chat if you disclose you relationship with it. Within reason of course: start spamming and it will be treated as spam. Of course, that doesn't guarantee that anyone will *take it*. Or is even this vorbotten?